# How to implement a List as a value in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

My requirement is to store a list of (Location ID + BITMAP) for each client. Example row is as follows:

- Key: Client ID
- Value: < (Location 1, Bitmap 1), (Location 2, Bitmap 2), ... , (Location N, Bitmap N) >

where

- 'Bitmap k' contains the history of which dates a client visited that location k.

The number of elements in Value could be varying from Client to Client, it could be 0 for some, could be 100 for some. I'd like to know how should this data be stored in MongoDB such that the following operations could be efficient:

1. Reset a particular BIT in all the Value pairs for all the rows
2. Update a particular BIT for some of the Value pairs for a row

An example for query 2 is as follows:

- ROW KEY: Client A
- ROW VALUE: < (Loc 1, BITWISE 1), (Loc 2, BITMASK 2), (Loc 3, BITMASK 3) >
- Query: Update Row with Key = 'Client A' set BIT # 8 for Loc IN (Loc 1, Loc 3)

Ultimately, I'd like to run a map-reduce query which should be able to iterate on each of the row value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51da846d9c34549b45432871"),
    "client_id" : "client_a",
    "values" : [
        {
            "location" : "loc_1",
            "bitmap" : [
                "000...",
                "111..."
            ]
        }
    ]
}

db.collection.find( { client_id: 'client_a', 'values.location': 'loc_1' } )
```

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. In value, I'd like to have more than just 1 location-bitmap pair. Could you now think of something which extends your given solution.

Comment: I'd like to know how I could do upsert kind of query into the array of location-bitmap pairs? 

Requirement is to set a bit for a location if the location exists, otherwise create a new location-bitwise pair element in the array.

I'm really hoping that the solution to this does not require a find() followed by update()/push(). If there's something like upsert query, that's what I'm looking for. If not, then can you suggest some other data structure for this purpose?

Comment: I see, I'll take a look at it and come back to you ;)